# How can the monarchy in Spain disappear?

Tags: constitution, monarchy, constitutional-monarchy, spain

At the moment, there is a monarchy in Spain for long time. Before was more important and relevant but nowadays it seems only as a figure that does not have such a relevance

What are the possibilities to disassemble the monarchy? With or without the agreement of the royalty or the goverment (I would like to know the most possible/realistic cases that will make the monarchy of Spain disassemble)

Comment: the French tried something that kinda seemed to work for a bit :) So did the Russians

Comment: @user4012 - I don't think the Russian style of getting rid of monarchy is recommended in the Western Europe :)

Comment: @Alexei, well French style wasn't any better, with all those guillotining, and then they had many swings back and forth between monarchy and republic.

Comment: haha Yes, I know these cases, but I dont think they can be apply for today´s Europe

Comment: "Change the government without agreement of the government" is usually the definition of both *coup d'état* and revolution

Comment: @SJuan76 I don´t ask about the goberment but about the monarchy, they are separeted in Spain. I ask to take away the monarchy but I dont care about the goberment

Comment: The king is the Head of State. You do not get to be more "government" than that. Any law approved must be signed by the Head of State; the fact that, even if so long he just rubber-stamps whatever gets approved by the Courts or PM does not change that. And, apart from that semantic detail, you have specified "without the agreement of the royalty **or the government**"; you did ask.

Comment: @SJuan76 That is why I wrote "with or without", to look for all the possibilities. Even he is the Head of State he maybe can accept to changes in the law or constitution thanks to pressures or whatever (that is why I am asking) and therefore not make a _coup d'état_ or revolution (at least a violent one as we are used to). There can be ways to make it without taking the streets and kill everyone :D

Comment: @user4012, so did the Spanish. In some senses it worked for almost 40 years, because a three-year civil war was followed by 36 years of dictatorship.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I think you are confused. King Alfonso XIII (did/was forced to) abdicate in 1931, and the 2nd Spanish Republic followed. In 1936 there was a right wing *coup d'état* that devolved into the Spanish Civil War (actually there were many others before) and ended with Franco's dictatorship. During Franco's dictatorship Alfonso XIII's heir returned to Spain and Franco appointed Juan Carlos I (Alfonso XIII's grandson) as his successor in 1969.

Comment: @user4012: Though I can't really see that the French or Russian methods (or the Spanish under Franco) led to much of an improvement.  Perhaps a better example would be Germany getting rid of the Kaiser (and all the other local monarchs).

Comment: @jamesqf Didn't the Germans get rid of the Kaiser after WWI? Which led to the Weimar Republic, superinflation and a guy named Hitler. Maybe not the best example as well?

Comment: @SdaliM: But the Kaiser left peacefully.  What happened afterwards is a separate matter.  E.g. the Weimar Republic didn't have to make the dumb decisions that it did.

Comment: @jamesqf Ok, seems fair. But with that in mind, does that means that in the 1789 example in France, the parliamentary monarchy isn't responsible for what happens after 1792, when the monarchy falls and the Terror begins?

Comment: @SdaliM: I don't know enough about that period of French history to give a meaningful answer.  Were the people running the parlimentary monarchy the same ones running the Terror, or was it different people who took over by a coup?  Maybe a better example would be the Russians, as the Communists were always pretty open about what they wanted to do to the "ruling class".

Comment: The most recent European monarchy to be abolished appears to be that of Greece, in 1974.  But that came at the end of a long road of unrest and dictatorship, and is probably not a great model to emulate.

Answer (score 8):

An elected government could start  re-drafting the constitution to remove the royalty from the constitution.

It would not be a easy negotiation.

If the negotiations are successful, the new constitution would need to be ratified by the Spaniards with a referendum and an election.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_Constitution_of_1978

**Protected provisions**

Title X of the Constitution establishes that the approval of a new constitution or the approval of any constitutional amendment affecting the Preliminary Title, or Section I of Chapter II of Title I (on Fundamental Rights and Public Liberties) or **Title II (on the Crown)**, the so-called "protected provisions", are subject to a special process that requires (1) that two-thirds of each House approve the amendment, (2) **that elections are called immediately thereafter**, (3) **that two-thirds of each new House approves the amendment**, and (4) that **the amendment is approved by the people in a referendum**.

----- Addendum -----

If the Spanish do remove the Royalty from the constitution, then by default the Royalty ceases to exists as they would lose most of their symbolic powers (and if it is case in Spain, they would also lose their salary...

http://www.ibtimes.com/how-much-does-king-spain-make-388346

Comment: Can this referendum be called without agreement of the monarchy? This page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monarchy_of_Spain says that the King can call a referendum, but not sure if it is needed for one.  Can the same monrchy disassemble itself without this process? For sure there are more options appar from your answer, but good one :D

Comment: @Ivan In Spain, the monarch sanctions some acts of government and parliament, but it's just a formal action. I'm sure a lot of steps in the process involve the king signature. Then the question is what happens if the king refuses to sign a legal act of government or parliament - about abolishing monarchy or about anything else.